# Getting Error On Stored Procedure while getting employee names from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this SQL Server stored procedure:

```
use PracticeDatabase
Go

alter procedure spGetEmpByGender
    @gender nvarchar(50),
    @name nvarchar(50) output
as
begin
    select @name = Emp_Name 
    from tblPracticeEmpTable 
    where gender = @gender
End

declare @EmpNames nvarchar(50)

exec spGetEmpByGender 'male', @EmpNames output

select @EmpNames
```

While executing the above procedure, I get this error:

> Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spGetEmpByGender, Line 10
>   Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level
>   exceeded (limit 32).

Comment: It is very likely that you will have more than 1 male in your table hence selecting solely on base of Gender isn't going to be a very definitive result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the following and see what happens

```
use PracticeDatabase
Go

IF OBJECT_ID('spGetEmpByGender') IS NOT NULL
  DROP PROCEDURE spGetEmpByGender
GO

CREATE procedure spGetEmpByGender
    @gender nvarchar(50),
    @name nvarchar(50) output
as
begin
    select Top 1 @name = Emp_Name 
    from tblPracticeEmpTable 
    where gender = @gender
End
GO


declare @EmpNames nvarchar(50)

exec spGetEmpByGender 'male', @EmpNames output

select @EmpNames
GO
```

Comment: it's retrieving a top first names , but i want all employee names having gender "Male".kindly suggest

Comment: you are getting back results in an output parameter, output parameter can only hold one scalar value, remove the output parameter and let procedure return a result set of all the employee names where gender = 'male'.

Comment: is it possible to get all employees with output parameter? or it holds only one scalar value?